# Integral $\int \ (2x+6)^5+\frac{10}{(3x-1)^2} \text{d}x$

Tags: integration

I don't know how to evaluate the following:

$$\int \ (2x+6)^5+\frac{10}{(3x-1)^2} \text{d}x$$

I know that I need to use something like a chain rule, but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int (2x+6)^5+\frac{10}{(3x-1)^2}dx =\int(2x+6)^5dx+\int10(3x-1)^{-2}dx$

In the first integral, let $u=2x+6$, then $du=2dx$ and thus $dx=du/2$,

So we have $\frac{1}{2}\int (u)^5du=\frac{1}{12}u^6=\frac{1}{12}(2x+6)^6$

As for the second integral, let $u=(3x-1)$ then $dx/du=\frac{1}{3}$

$\frac{10}{3}\int u^{-2}du=-\frac{10}{3}u^{-1}=-\frac{10}{3}(3x-1)^-1$

Sum them up, and you'll have the solution: $\frac{1}{12}(2x+6)^6-\frac{10}{3(3x-1)}+c$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral into a sum of integrals, then think about the antiderivative of $1/x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\int (2x + 6)^5 dx + \int \frac{1}{(3x-1)^2}dx$$

Use [$u$ substitution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b76wePnIBdU).

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x^mdx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} \\$$$$\int (ax+b)^mdx=\frac{(ax+b)^{m+1}}{(m+1)a} \\$$